What is the difference between 'is to be distinguished from' and 'is distinguished from'?

This case is to be distinguished, however, from She was driving [a
Cortina], where Cortina is a tradename but not a proper name.

How does 'to be' function? 'is to be distinguished from' and 'is distinguished from' seem to have a very similar meaning, but what is the author's intention to use 'is to be...'?

Overall, either "is to be distinguished" or "is distinguished" can be correct.
But, to answer your question, the usage of 'to be' in this passage can signify one of two things based on the context and tone of the writer:
The more likely meaning: The writer is using a guiding, instructing tone, and places emphasis on how the reader should think about the case.
It's like saying "Take note of the difference between these two cases" instead of saying "There is a difference between the cases."
Saying "is to be distinguished" conveys that the reader should actively 'be' noting a difference between the two cases.
On the other hand, saying "is distinguished from" signifies a straightforward, objective tone. It assumes that the difference between the cases is obvious. It is a mere statement of fact, and not the best tone for guiding someone through a tricky topic.

The less likely meaning: 'to be' can mean 'something that is yet to be determined': The case is not distinguished yet, and it is 'to be' distinguished in the future by someone else.
An example of this type of usage of 'to be': "Research about social media use and mental illness is inconclusive, and in order to be more sure about a potential link, more studies are to be done.

Saying "is to be distinguished" conveys that the reader should actively 'be' noting a difference between the two cases.=RIGHT. :)

The passive infinitive form to be distinguished can be understood, in context, either as a statement about the future, synonymous with "will be", or as synonymous with modal must.

You are to be must be praised  for your question.
Let Security know that any vehicles blocking the entry are to be must be towed away, and they must see to it promptly.


She is to be given an award  will be given an award at the next assembly.

So, in your example, the reader is being informed of the need to distinguish the cases. They must be treated differently.

is distinguised by x is passive, so is: is to be distinguished by x. Both would be passive.

@Lambie I don't think there's unanimous agreement on that when distinguished plays an adjectival role.   The situation is distinguished from Cortina because it doesn't involve a trade name  I'd say that one of the adjectival meanings of distinguished is "distinct from"

You say it is not passive and I say either can be passive. "There's the active form is distinguished and the passive form is to be distinguished".=Not true. The active form is: distinguish. We can distinguish the difference between A and B.

Would you consider this a passive construction: "That much is understood"?

Of course, That much is understood [by us, by me, by them, etc.]

I've eliminated the part treating is distinguished as active on the grounds that  it was not a passive verbal construction but adjectival.  If you want to lump it under "Passive Constructions of All Kinds" that's fine with me, though I would distinguish between passive constructions that draw attention to the do-er and those in which a do-er is largely irrelevant to the meaning, as in "We couldn't get in because the door was locked".

I think there are two distinct meanings of modal be to. One of them indicates that the action described in the clause has already been decided or arranged or when used performatively may be understood as a decree by the speaker . The other meaning is something like should (rather than must). But that's just my thoughts. Certainly, is to seems to mean should rather than must in OP's example, I reckon.

Agreed, I wasn't pushing  must as far to the right on the modal spectrum as a decree. But must is on a gradient and on the end of the spectrum opposite "decree" it can mean "really ought to"  or "truly deserve to".
